# reading multi-digit numbers from a char string in MIPS (assembly code)

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I'm trying to read a string from a user in order to evaluate an expression. For example I want to compute ((2-(8*9))*1-4)). To accomplish this, I convert the characters of the numbers read to the actual number they represent while saving them back into the string with the code below. My algorithm works great when I input digits of (0-9) in between operation commands '* - ( ) / '. But I need to make it work when inputting multi-digit numbers in my string. For example, ((20-(8*91))*1-43)). I know the algorithm to convert, lets say 3 1 4 into 314, but my question is, how can I insert it back into my byte string while maintaining the same order on the following characters? I've tried many ways, but can't get it to work. thanks in advance

```
.data

expression: .space 110            # to store string
stack: .space 110                 # to help with operations

.text


#______reading string from user
li $v0, 8
li $a1, 100
la $a0, expression
syscall
#_____________________________



#___count number of characters in string 
la $s0, expression                           #s0 = adress of string  
li $t1, 0                                      #t1 = # characters
loopcounter:
lb $t0, ($s0)
beq $t0, '\n', outcounter
addi $t1, $t1, 1
addi $s0, $s0, 1
j loopcounter

outcounter:             #if you want to print the amount of characters in the  string
#li $v0, 1
#move $a0, $t1
#syscall
#_______________________________________



#__convert number characters into integers
la $s0, expression                            #s0 = adress of string 
li $t0, 1                                       #t0 loop counter
loopStringtoNum:                               
lb $t2, ($s0)                                    #t2 = ASCII of a digit
blt $t2, '0', skipCharConversion
bgt $t2, '9', skipCharConversion
subi $t2, $t2, 0x30                            #t1 = the digit
sb $t2, ($s0)   
skipCharConversion:
addi $s0, $s0, 1
addi $t0, $t0, 1
ble $t0, $t1, loopStringtoNum                  #skip string to num loop
#_________________________________________
```

Comment: I don't see much point in trying to store binary data back into the text. You won't even be able to tell the difference.

Comment: So, are you looking for the algorithms for `atoi` and `itoa`?